# Работа с чекбоксами в gui приложении tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, gui, checkbox

Не знаю как заставить правильно работать чекбоксы в моём приложении. Я создаю генератор паролей (используя tkinter, как вы уже поняли из названия).

И я не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы когда ставишь флаг на спец. символы, к примеру, они обязательно были в исходном пароле и т.п. Надеюсь вы поняли чего я хочу. Но это не всё. Мне пришла такая идея:
1. Я создаю строку
2. Если, например, чекбокс с цифрами нажат, то я конкатенирую эту строку с другой строкой в которой цифры. И так с каждым
3. Генерирую пароль из этой строки (путём random.choice) до того, пока он не будет содержать нужные символы

Но, вы скорее всего уже догадались, с реализацией у меня возникли проблемы. Помогите, пожалуйста)

Вот чистый код (без чекбоксов). Алгоритм писать в getResult()

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import string

root = Tk()
root.title("PassGen++")
root.resizable(False, False)
# root.iconbitmap("icon.ico")

# Containers for checkboxes

digitsContainer = IntVar()
sLettersContainer = IntVar()
bLettersContainer = IntVar()
symbolsContainer = IntVar()

# Output area

outputArea = Label(root, text="OUTPUT WILL BE HERE", font="Consolas 16", fg="#1E5740")

# Select the quantity of the symbols

passwordNumber = Scale(root, orient="horizontal", font="Consolas 11 bold", from_=5, to=50, length=485, bg="#38ae7e",
                       activebackground="#39AF7F", fg="#F0F0F0")


def scalePlus(event):
    i = passwordNumber.get() + 1
    passwordNumber.set(i)


def scaleMinus(event):
    i = passwordNumber.get() - 1
    passwordNumber.set(i)


plusButton = Button(root, text="+", font="Consolas 14 bold", relief="groove", bg="#38ae7e", activebackground="#39AF7F",
                    fg="#F0F0F0", activeforeground="#E8E8E8")
plusButton.bind("<Button-1>", scalePlus)
minusButton = Button(root, text="-", font="Consolas 14 bold", relief="groove", bg="#38ae7e", activebackground="#39AF7F",
                     fg="#F0F0F0", activeforeground="#E8E8E8")
minusButton.bind("<Button-1>", scaleMinus)

# Checkboxes and other additions

checkDigits = Checkbutton(root, text="0-9", variable=digitsContainer, height=2, fg="#1E5740", font="Consolas 10 bold",
                          activeforeground="#1E5740")
checkSLetters = Checkbutton(root, text="a-z", variable=sLettersContainer, height=2, fg="#1E5740", font="Consolas 10 "
                                                                                                       "bold",
                            activeforeground="#1E5740")
checkBLetters = Checkbutton(root, text="A-Z", variable=bLettersContainer, height=2, fg="#1E5740", font="Consolas 10 "
                                                                                                       "bold",
                            activeforeground="#1E5740")
checkSymbols = Checkbutton(root, text="#$*", variable=symbolsContainer, height=2, fg="#1E5740", font="Consolas 10 bold",
                           activeforeground="#1E5740")

additionsLabel = Label(root, text="Other symbols:", fg="#1E5740", font="Consolas 10 bold")
additionsEntry = Entry(root)


# Function for get result from generate button
# ----------------------------------------------------------


def getResult(event):
    passwordLength = int(passwordNumber.get())

    digits = random.randint(0, passwordLength)
    letters = passwordLength - digits

    result = []

    for digit in range(digits):
        result.append(str(random.randint(0, 9)))
    for letter in range(letters):
        result.append(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))

    # Block with other symbols
    # ---------------------------------

    # ----------------------------------

    i = 0
    while i < passwordLength:
        j = random.randint(0, passwordLength - 1)
        tmp = result[j]
        result[j] = result[i]
        result[i] = tmp
        i += 1
    outputArea["text"] = "".join(result)


# ----------------------------------------------------------


# Function for copy result from output area

def copyResult(event):
    root.clipboard_clear()
    root.clipboard_append(outputArea["text"])


# Main GENERATE button and other help buttons

generateButton = Button(root, text="--> GENERATE <--", font="Consolas 14 bold", relief="groove", bg="#38ae7e",
                        activebackground="#39AF7F", fg="#F0F0F0", activeforeground="#E8E8E8")
generateButton.bind("<Button-1>", getResult)
copyButton = Button(root, text="COPY PASSWORD", font="Consolas 14 bold", relief="groove", bg="#38ae7e",
                    activebackground="#39AF7F", fg="#F0F0F0", activeforeground="#E8E8E8")
copyButton.bind("<Button-1>", copyResult)
aboutUsButton = Button(root, text="ABOUT\nUS", font="Consolas 10 bold", relief="groove", bg="#38ae7e",
                       activebackground="#39AF7F", fg="#F0F0F0", activeforeground="#E8E8E8")
exitButton = Button(root, text="EXIT", font="Consolas 10 bold", relief="groove", command=root.quit, bg="#38ae7e",
                    activebackground="#39AF7F", fg="#F0F0F0", activeforeground="#E8E8E8")

# Placement

outputArea.grid(row=0, columnspan=4, sticky=N + S + W + E, pady=2, padx=2)

plusButton.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=N + S + W + E, padx=2)
minusButton.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N + S + W + E, padx=2)
passwordNumber.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)

checkDigits.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=2)
checkSLetters.grid(row=3, column=1)
checkBLetters.grid(row=3, column=2)
checkSymbols.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=2)

additionsLabel.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=E)
additionsEntry.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W)

generateButton.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=N + S + W + E, pady=4, padx=2)
copyButton.grid(row=6, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=N + S + W + E, pady=2, padx=2)
aboutUsButton.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=N + S + W + E, pady=2, padx=2)
exitButton.grid(row=6, column=3, sticky=N + S + W + E, pady=2, padx=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предложенные вами алгоритм создания пароля создаёт более предсказуемые пароли и плохо поддаётся расширению функционала. Предлагаю такой алгоритм:

1. Создаём базу пароля (список всех разрешённых символов) на основе настроек пользователя (в Вашем случае по чекбоксам);
2. В бесконечном цикле создаём пароль нужной длины путём выбирания из базы пароля по символу без удаления;
3. В этом же цикле проверяем пароль на соответсвие настройкам пользователя;
4. Если такой пароль найден, заканчиваем цикл и возвращаем пароль.

```py
import string
import random

symbols = ['!', '$', '&']

# Предположим, что нужно создавать пароль из цифр, английских букв верхнего и нижнего регистра и спецсимволов
def get_result():
  # Получаем длину пароля из полей
  password_length = 12
  # Список всех допустимых в пароле символов (база пароля)
  password_base = []
  # Получать разрешение на использование нужных символом из чекбоксов
  allow_lowercase_letters = True
  allow_uppercase_letters = True
  allow_digits = True
  allow_symbols = True

  # Заполняем базу пароля по разрешениям
  if allow_lowercase_letters:
    password_base += list(string.ascii_lowercase)
  if allow_uppercase_letters:
    password_base += list(string.ascii_uppercase)
  if allow_digits:
    password_base += list(string.digits)
  if allow_symbols:
    password_base += symbols # И иные спецсимволы

  while True:
    # Создаём случайный пароль нужной длины в списке
    password_temp = []
    for i in range(password_length):
      password_temp.append(random.choice(password_base))
    # Проверяем на корректность путём проверки пересечения множеств символов
    # из сгенерированного пароля и разрешённых символов
    if \
            (not allow_lowercase_letters or (set(password_temp) & set(string.ascii_lowercase))) \
        and (not allow_uppercase_letters or (set(password_temp) & set(string.ascii_uppercase))) \
        and (not allow_digits or (set(password_temp) & set(string.digits))) \
        and (not allow_symbols or (set(password_temp) & set(symbols))):
        break
  return ''.join(password_temp)
```

По нажанию по изменению настроек создания пароля (по нажатию на чекбокс) снова вызывать этот метод, чтобы результат всегда соответствовал настройкам.